# ASP.Net MVC 5 - OWIN Authentication login redirect display message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I’m using OWIN based authentication in my MVC application. 
All my controllers and action methods are secured using a custom AuthorizeAttribute.

Currently if a user request a page with insufficient permissions (User has no access because he is not in the group which has access to the function) he gets redirected to the login page.
This behavior could confuse the user because he doesn’t know why he was redirected to the login page.

Is it possible to display a message in this case?
…Can OWIN add a parameter to the login-page request (something like the ReturnUrl parameter)?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false )]
public class FunctionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IUserInformationService UserInformationService { get; set; }
    public IGenericParameterService GenericParameterService { get; set; }
    public String FunctionName { get; set; }

    public FunctionAuthorizeAttribute( String functionName )
    {
        FunctionName = functionName;
    }

    protected override Boolean AuthorizeCore( HttpContextBase httpContext )
    {
        var parameter = GenericParameterService.GetCommonParameters();
        if ( !parameter.CacheSecurityParameter )
            parameter = GenericParameterService.GetCommonParameters(false);

        return !parameter.EnableAuthentication || UserInformationService.HasAccess( FunctionName )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your custom attribute?

Comment: @Kamo Sure, but you won’t find anything interesting in there… I guess.
I’ve added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use session store. I usually store messages to be displayed on the next screen display in a session variable (as a list). The layout page is then responsible to display an appropriate message:

```
SessionMessage.AddMessage("Huh - you should login first", SessionMessage.MessageType.warning);
```

with code in Views/Account/Login.cshtml:

```
@foreach (SessionEntry item in SessionMessage.GetSessionEntries())
{
   <div class="alert alert-@(Enum.GetName(typeof(SessionMessage.MessageType), item.MessageType).ToLower())">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
       @item.Message
       </div>
}
```

With all the rest [here](https://gist.github.com/steven-r/2c5897e907f38efbff9d).

Comment: You would probably be better of storing the errors in the TempData object, as its only available for then one request and is then automatically cleared.

Comment: I've had the problem whit TempData that the information got lost on multiple redirects (especially in the context of OWIN and Azure Active Directory). Therefore I've switched to the session approach.